# Neither $_POST nor $_GET are working

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

I made a products list (22 items) and in one of the columns i added a textbox so the user could add the quantity that he wants. Once pressed submit i want to write in an empty table the ProductID , price and quantity. The problem is that Neither $_POST nor $_GET are getting this data.

When I used $_GET i noticed in the URL that  the data has been taken but then when i tried to write it on the database or to echo it nothing came out and i get the error : **Notice: Undefined index: Quantità**

This is the products page :

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['codcliente'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo"<html>
<body>
<h1>Catalogo Prodotti</h1>
Sei loggato con l'account <b>".strtoupper($username)."</b>.<a href=\"Logout.php\">Clicca qui</a> per fare il LOGOUT!<br/><br/>
<form action=ordine.php method='POST'>
<input type='submit' name ='submit' value='Inserisci'>
</form>";

echo "<table border=1 align=center>
<tr>
<td align=center><b>CodProdotto</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Nome</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Prezzo Unitario</b></td>
<td align=center><b>Quantità</b></td>
</tr>";

$query = "SELECT CodProdotto,Nome,Prezzo FROM Prodotto";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


    do{
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
        $codprodotto = $row['CodProdotto'];
        $nome = $row['Nome'];
        $prezzo = $row['Prezzo'];
        echo "<tr>
        <td align=center>$codprodotto</td>
        <td align=center>$nome</td>
        <td align=center>$prezzo &#x20ac</td>
        <td><p ><input type='text' name='Quantità' style=width:80px ></p></td>
        </tr>";
    }while($row != NULL);   

echo "</table>";


mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the form :

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['codcliente'];
$username = $_SESSION['username'];

echo"<html>
<body>
<h1>Ordine</h1>
Sei loggato con l'account <b>".strtoupper($username)."</b>.<a href=\"Logout.php\">Clicca qui</a> per fare il LOGOUT!<br/><br/>";

$query= "SELECT CodProdotto,Prezzo FROM prodotto";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<form action='Consegna.php'>
<p><input type='submit' Value='Inserisci dati consegna'></p>
</form>";  
//$n = 0;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
do {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
if ($row != NULL) {
$codprodotto = $row["CodProdotto"];
$prezzo = $row["Prezzo"];
$quantita = $_POST["Quantità"];
$query="INSERT INTO ordineprodotto(CodProdotto,Prezzo,Quantita) VALUES('$codprodotto','$prezzo','$quantita')";
$risultato= mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo mysql_error();
}
}while ($row!=NULL);
}



echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

I'm stuck at this problem since 3 days and I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Your form ends with just submit button.. so no HTML element inside it and hence nothing is working !!

Comment: The `<input>` elements have to be between `<form>` and `</form>`.

Comment: Just curious, why are you echoing all the HTML, you should have left that outside the PHP tag. Your code is a complete mess

Comment: @Barmar this was the problem!! now it's getting the data even if it s writing into all the rows the same quantity (the value that i inserted in the last textbox )

Comment: @AkhilSidharth Hehe yeah i know it's just that I'm new to it and still learning.. Any suggestion to fix it up a bit it's very welcomed! :)

Comment: You need to use array-style names `name='Quantita[]'`. Then `$_POST['Quantita']` will be an array you can loop over.

Comment: Don't code in native language - it will hard for foreign people to understand you [and posting code on SO is a more than valid case ^^].

Comment: @barmar Sorry for this dumb question but how can I specific that quantita is an array

Comment: Something like: `foreach ($_POST['Quantita'] AS $quantita) { ... }`

Comment: @Barmar I tried as you said but i got "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: If you made the change to the HTML that I suggested, that shouldn't happen. The two changes go together.

Comment: @Barmar What I did till now is change the form closing tag ( and now it's working ) and i added the foreach after 'code'if ($row != NULL) { 'code' and removed 'code'$quantita = $_POST["Quantità"];'code'

where should I place the foreach ? Sorry for bothering you but you don't know how much you are helping me!

Comment: @Barmar if you could just post me where should i put the for each that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, your codes doesn't make much sense, so i took the liberty of modifying it. What i think your are trying, is to list all the values along with a input box for Quantita. when you press the submit button Inserisci, it should enter data into ordineprodotto. i suppose one is the form & other is the insertion page. if i am right, try the code below

```
<?php
require ("connect.php");
session_start();
//$userid = $_SESSION['codcliente']; //Didnt find any use of this variable
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "SELECT CodProdotto,Nome,Prezzo FROM Prodotto";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if($_REQUEST['submit']=="Inserisci"){
    $CodProdotto_array=$_REQUEST['CodProdotto'];
    $Nome_array=$_REQUEST['Nome'];
    $Prezzo_array=$_REQUEST['Prezzo'];
    $Quantita_array=$_REQUEST['Quantita'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($CodProdotto_array);$i++){
        $CodProdotto=mysql_real_escape_string($CodProdotto_array[$i]);
        $Nome=mysql_real_escape_string($Nome_array[$i]);
        $Prezzo=mysql_real_escape_string($Prezzo_array[$i]);
        $Quantita=mysql_real_escape_string($Quantita_array[$i]);
        $query2="INSERT INTO ordineprodotto(CodProdotto,Prezzo,Quantita) VALUES('".$CodProdotto."','".$Prezzo."','".$Quantita."')";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Catalogo Prodotti</h1>
        Sei loggato con l'account <b><?php echo strtoupper($username);?></b>
        <a href="Logout.php">Clicca qui</a>per fare il LOGOUT!<br/><br/>
        <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inserisci">
        <table border=1 align=center>
            <tr>
                <td align=center><b>CodProdotto</b></td>
                <td align=center><b>Nome</b></td>
                <td align=center><b>Prezzo Unitario</b></td>
                <td align=center><b>Quantità</b></td>
            </tr>
        <?php  if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
                    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
            <tr>
                <input type="hidden" name="CodProdotto[]" value="<?php echo $row['CodProdotto'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="Nome[]" value="<?php echo $row['Nome'];?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="Prezzo[]" value="<?php echo $row['Prezzo'];?>">
                <td align=center><?php echo $row['CodProdotto'];?></td>
                <td align=center><?php echo $row['Nome']; ?></td>
                <td align=center><?php echo $row['Prezzo']; ?> &#x20ac </td>
                <td><p ><input type="text" name="Quantita[]" style="width:80px"></p></td>
        </tr>
            <?php }
                } else {?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">No Values to Display</td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW! it works perfectly!! thank you a lot for your help  you saved me days of work tho ! i had to delete mysql_real_escape_string because it was giving me error telling that the inserted value was wrong

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake with the mysql_real_escape_string. i placed it in the wrong part. i have corrected the code. try it. i haven't done javascript validation, i suggest you also do that. if you are fully satisfied with my answer, please approve it.

Answer (score 0):

The `form` is closed before the input fields.

Place `<input type='submit' name ='submit' value='Inserisci'>
</form>` after the `</table>`.

Comment: thank you!! this was the problem :D now it's getting the data even if it s writing into all the rows the same quantity (the value that i inserted in the last textbox )

Comment: Because you have to give unique `name` to each `input` field. For example add a variable after each `name='Quantità'` what you increment continually: `name='Quantita_1'` `name='Quantita_2'`, etc.

Comment: They suggested me to use array with foreach 
"($_POST['Quantita'] AS $quantita) { ... }" but i got this error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: Maybe because of the accent (à)? Remove it from everywhere.

Comment: No because I changed that :S where should I put the foreach ? 
i added the foreach after "if ($row != NULL) { " and removed "$quantita = $_POST["Quantità"];"

Comment: could you please tell me where should i write the foreach?